# Subset Sum Problem Variant With Successive Numbers

Tags: discrete-mathematics

The subset sum problem is hard - so given the following restraints, I am hoping the following is much easier to solve.  Given a set $S$ contains $m$ elements from $n$ to $m$, where:

- 0 < $n$ < $m$
- $n$, $m$ ∈ Z<sup>+</sup>
- S = {n, n+1, n+2, ... n+(m-1)}

What is the subset of the most common sums?  What is the subset of the most common sums from summing x-elements from the set, where x ≤ ($m$-1)?  I am hoping for a trivial solution due to all elements being successive, but I may not get one.

Comment: "Given a set S contains m elements from n to m, " y elements ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a given number of terms the most common sum is the number of terms times the average, $x\frac {2n+m-1}2$ or the numbers on either side if this is a half integer.  Note that you can subtract $n$ from all the elements in your set and ask the same question with the set being $[0,m-1]$ if you reduce all the sums by $xn$.  The maximum comes when $x=2$ where there are $\frac {m-1}2$ pairs if $m$ is odd and $\frac {m}2$ when $m$ is even.  There would be another if $m$ is odd if you permitted doubles-two numbers that are both $\frac {m+1}2$ and there are three sums equally probable, the one cited above and one each side.

I would guess that for all sizes of subset together the peak comes when you do the above with half the elements, so the sum would be $\frac{m}2\cdot \frac {2n+m-1}2$ but I have not proven it.